# Updating create_function Inside Wordpress add_filter()

Tags: php, wordpress

Just updated another Wordpress site from PHP 7.4 to 8.1 and needed to update the deprecated create_function. Here's the old code:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$cols', 'return '.$sp_products_per_page.';' ), 20 );
```

I updated it to:

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) { return $sp_products_per_page; }, 20);
```

But it still doesn't seem to be working correctly. Is this syntax correct?

Answer (score 1):

From the two functions you have, I assume it's a scope issue.

`$sp_products_per_page` is declared/exists on a global scope, and because you use an anonymous function, it's not accessible from the function scope.
So instead of

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) { return $sp_products_per_page; }, 20);
```

You'll need to add a `use` keyword

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) use ($sp_products_per_page) { return $sp_products_per_page; }, 20);
```

A bit of formatting and we have this

```php
add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', function($cols) use ($sp_products_per_page) {
    return $sp_products_per_page;
}, 20);
```